# Is there a minimal constructible model for every first order theory that has some?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

If a first order theory $T$ has a constructible model, then does that entail that $T$ must have a minimal constructible model, i.e. one that is homomorphic to every constructible model of $T$.

By "constructible model" I just mean a model that is an element of $L$. Formally: $$\mathcal M \text { is a constructible model of } T \iff\\ (\mathcal M \models T) \land \mathcal M \in L$$

Comment: By "constructible model", do you mean the notion from model theory? A constructible model over $A$ is a model containing $A$ and enumerated as $(m_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, such that for all $\beta$ the type of $m_\beta$ over its predecessors and $A$ is isolated. If this is not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: No, I just mean an element of Godel's constructible universe. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, certainly not. If you take a consistent theory $T$ with no minimal model (provably  in ZFC), then the same proof will go through in $L$, which shows that $T$ has a model in $L$ but no minimal model in $L$. Or am I missing something?